# Ubuntu16.04 No Audio Output

Tags: 16.04, sound, pulseaudio

I'm a Ubuntu newbie and I recently installed Ubuntu 16.04 on my XPS13. It worked well at first but today I just find that there's no audio output, both headphone and laptop speaker.I tried several ways in forum such as reinstall `alsa-base` and `pulseaudio`, but things seem to become worse that even the sound icon on the top bar disappeared.Now in *settings → sound* it looks like this:

[image]

The first line in picture seems to be info of my external screen connected with HDMI.

```
$ lspci -nnk | grep -A2 Audio
00:03.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Audio Controller [8086:160c] (rev 09)
    Subsystem: Dell Broadwell-U Audio Controller [1028:0665]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
--
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP High Definition Audio Controller [8086:9ca0] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Dell Wildcat Point-LP High Definition Audio Controller [1028:0665]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel

$ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC3263 Analog [ALC3263 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

pactl list short sinks
0   alsa_output.pci-0000_00_03.0.hdmi-surround71    module-alsa-card.c  s16le 8ch 44100Hz   SUSPENDED
1   alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo  module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 44100Hz   SUSPENDED
```

More info on sink #1:

```
State: SUSPENDED
Name: alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo
Description: Built-in Audio Analog Stereo
Driver: module-alsa-card.c
Sample Specification: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
Channel Map: front-left,front-right
Owner Module: 7
Mute: yes
Volume: front-left: 21845 /  33% / -28.63 dB,   front-right: 21845 /  33% / -28.63 dB
        balance 0.00
Base Volume: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
Monitor Source: alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo.monitor
Latency: 0 usec, configured 0 usec
Flags: HARDWARE HW_MUTE_CTRL HW_VOLUME_CTRL DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY 
Properties:
    alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
    device.api = "alsa"
    device.class = "sound"
    alsa.class = "generic"
    alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
    alsa.name = "ALC3263 Analog"
    alsa.id = "ALC3263 Analog"
    alsa.subdevice = "0"
    alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
    alsa.device = "0"
    alsa.card = "1"
    alsa.card_name = "HDA Intel PCH"
    alsa.long_card_name = "HDA Intel PCH at 0xf7418000 irq 49"
    alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
    device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:1b.0"
    sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card1"
    device.bus = "pci"
    device.vendor.id = "8086"
    device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
    device.product.id = "9ca0"
    device.product.name = "Wildcat Point-LP High Definition Audio Controller"
    device.form_factor = "internal"
    device.string = "front:1"
    device.buffering.buffer_size = "65536"
    device.buffering.fragment_size = "32768"
    device.access_mode = "mmap+timer"
    device.profile.name = "analog-stereo"
    device.profile.description = "Analog Stereo"
    device.description = "Built-in Audio Analog Stereo"
    alsa.mixer_name = "Realtek ALC3263"
    alsa.components = "HDA:10ec0288,10280665,00100003"
    module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
    device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
Ports:
    analog-output-speaker: Speakers (priority: 10000)
    analog-output-headphones: Headphones (priority: 9000, not available)
Active Port: analog-output-speaker
Formats:
    pcm
```

I switched to my Windows system and audio can't work too, is my audio card broken due to my hot-plug of HDMI?

I reinstall my Windows and it works but I still don't know what happened.

[image]

Comment: did you tried installing drivers??

Comment: I had to run the command `pulseaudio -D` (if it works, put it in ~/.bash_profile) [you may need to `sudo apt purge pulseaudio && sudo apt install pulseaudio` first]

Comment: Solved what? Are you not interested to find a solution anymore?

Comment: @Anwar Edit it again, I do want to know what happened but not understand "SOLVED" tag well, thank you for advice!

Comment: @SmitPatil System audio worked well yesterday and I didn't install drivers by myself after installing Ubuntu because audio worked.Is that still possible drivers result in the problem?

Comment: If you're only interested to know what happened I'd say it's very difficult given that you removed Ubuntu completely now. As a general advice, Always use text instead of screenshot when you post some command's output. It improves accessibility of the site and helps and requires less time

Comment: @Anwar I didn't remove Ubuntu but reinstalled Windows(dual-boot), and that's what confused me most, why changes in Windows will affect Ubuntu?

Comment: @Mindong Maybe something from sound firmware was causing the problem and some windows program fixed it. This is not extraordinary and may happen

Comment: @Anwar It sounds reasonable.Since my audio system works again, what I can only provide with is the second picture and I wonder if it contains any useful information.Thank you for your time!

Comment: @DavidFoerster Hello, I type the comments and the output is in the second picture(I'll use text next time), is it containing some useful information?

Comment: @DavidFoerster I re-edit my question just now. `LC_MESSAGES=POSIX pactl list sinks | grep -B2 -A99 -e '^\s*Name:.*broadwell'` output nothing so I post output of the first part of command instead. Why this problem will affect both OS (Windows 10 and Ubuntu), is it  a firmware error?

Comment: @DavidFoerster The output is complete and the Broadwell audio device do not show up here.

Comment: @DavidFoerster Internal audio is here now and I add the current screenshot , but when problem happened the panel was whole blank, and I plugged in HDMI so there's device in the first screenshot . Would you please explain the reason behind, thanks!

Comment: It's very hard to say because post-mortem analyses are difficult or impossible if the configuration and system state to analyse were erased. I'm voting to close this question as off topic because 1) the original problem went away and 2) the remaining question "How did it happen?" cannot be answered feasibly if you can't reproduce the original problem.

Comment: @DavidFoerster It's reasonable and really appreciate your help!